# Which FAA regulations cover the certification of aircraft engines?

Tags: faa-regulations

Aircraft certification is covered by 14 CFR 23 and 25, what parts cover aircraft engines?

Answer (score 3):

The relevant section of the FARs for engine certification standards is [14CFR33 - AIRWORTHINESS STANDARDS: AIRCRAFT ENGINES](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr33_main_02.tpl), with 33.31 through 33.57 dealing with reciprocating (piston) powerplants & their testing requirements, and 33.61 through 33.99 being the equivalent for turbine powerplants.

There are also the [33 series Advisory Circulars](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.list/parentTopicID/109) dealing with such fun topics as how to comply with the [Bird Ingestion Certification Standards (33.76-1A)](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/99690).